# Allow users to adjust the window size in an Angular 8 application?

Tags: angular, typescript, resize, window

New to Angular, as well as a first-time poster here on stackoverflow. So don't judge me lol.

I'm looking for a way to resize the window of an angular application. Similar to a browsers zoom in and out setting. Difference is I want users to be able to set this setting inside of my angular application. I have spent a lot of time trying to find materials online but with no luck so far, so thought I'd see if any one here might have done something like this?

Comment: So you'd like the user to be able to dynamically set the zoom of the window within your app?

Comment: @user2091374 precisely

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 //Component.html:
 <input [value]="zoom" (change)="onzoom()" (input)="zoom = $event.target.value">%

 //Component.ts: 
 zoom = 0;
 onzoom() {
   document.body.style.zoom = this.zoom + "%";
 }
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fafsjx